# Can't pass session variable between pages

Tags: php, session, header

So I have one page with setting session variable.

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
if ($user->resetPassword($_POST['password'], $email) == true) {
    $_SESSION["pesanberhasil"] = "Berhasil ubah password";
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
} else {
    $error = "Gagal ubah password";
}
```

}

In my logic and my experience using session variable it should work well. (I have session start on top of this code, so it should not be a problem). The problem when the page is redirected to the location, and i put

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

or

```
var_dump($_SESSION["pesanberhasil"]);
```

it always say empty array. The location page have session start on top of the code as well. I have similar situation on the other part of my website and it works well.

I tried to put var_dump and die after setting the session variable and it shows the session variable is set. So i guess its nothing related to the if statement. I also try to put the header this way.

```
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    if ($user->resetPassword($_POST['password'], $email) == true) {
        $_SESSION["pesanberhasil"] = "Berhasil ubah password";
    } else {
        $error = "Gagal ubah password";
    }
header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
}
```

but still the same problem.

Comment: Not sure if it'll help but try `exit;` after the header.

Comment: Also, what happens if you `echo $_SESSION["pesanberhasil"] = "Berhasil ubah password";`?  Maybe it's not entering the `if`.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I already tried to var dump the session variable before redirected (same like echo) and it shows the variable is set. I already try the exit too.

Comment: Make sure you have error_reporting on, you may be getting a header warning on the second page.

Comment: Is that the same page you're redirecting to using `header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);`? If not, does "the other" page also have `session_start();`?

Comment: No it's not the same page, and I have session start in the other page